# Hermitian Operators in time and Measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider an observable that can be described by a hermitian operator $A$ . No explicit relationship with time is given. What would happen to the probability if the quantity is measured a few days later?

Comment: Is this operator given in Schrodinger or Heisenberg picture?

Comment: I would say depends on the operator.

Comment: The operator is in the Schrodinger picture. It is a question on measurements and how they affect observables.

Comment: In general the operator won't change over time, but the state the system is in will change over time, depending on the commutation relationship between the operator and the hamiltonian.  http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/quantum-entanglements/lecture-9/time-evolution-of-observables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time evolution of observables in the Schrodinger picture is determined by the wave function. So, the operator itself can say nothing about the time evolution. To get this information one has to know the Hamiltonian of the system and solve time-dependent Schrodinger equation. In turn, Schrodinger equation requires knowing of initial conditions. So, how the system was prepared at the initial moment will influence on the final result.

Also, you can use a property that Hermitian operator has real eigenvalues $\hat{O}\psi(\mathbf{r})=a\psi(\mathbf{r})$:

$$\int d \mathbf{r}\psi^*(\mathbf{r})\hat{O}\psi(\mathbf{r})=a \int d \mathbf{r}\psi^*(\mathbf{r})\psi(\mathbf{r})=a$$

Comment: Correct.  If the operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, then the observable won't change over time.

Comment: hmmmm okay. Let us assume a $\psi = C(u_1 (x) + e^(i\phi)u_2(x))$ That is all the information provided.

Comment: Does not the wave function depend on time?

Comment: @Artemisia If the wave function does not depend on time and the operator has no explicit time dependence then the measurement will the results with same probability whenever u measure it

Comment: This was the function provided... no explicit time dependence